# Can we apply gravity to only one object

Tags: objects, physics

I have two main objects in my scene. One is a player and another is a spaceship. I want to apply gravity to only one object. Can i do that?

Comment: could you please tell more, do you mean that the 2 objects are not affected the same way by the gravity?

Comment: They are, actually I want one object on the ground while the other to float.

Comment: maybe this is the same question here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221277/is-it-possible-to-change-the-gravity-of-a-single-rigid-body-in-the-scene

Comment: Can't understand it properly, and it's a very old version.... Can you suggest me any tutorial? I shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: from this answer it looks like you can't have several gravities in the same scene, if this is what you want